# What Should I Do With Serial Down-Voters?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

Recently, some user has started down-voting my posts without any reasons consecutively! I call them **serial down-voters**! :)

What should I do?

Comment: Moderators can see some aggregate voting data. It lists the users who have cast more than a smallish number of either upvotes/downvotes to you or received votes from you. In your case the only downvotes to/from you that don't fall below this radar are downvotes that **you** cast.

Comment: The question you wrote here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582594/evaluating-the-definite-integral-int-01-frac2-sin-pi-x-cos-pi-x1x/1583063#1583063 has at least one issue: no motivation is given for the original integral, much less for the generalized family. The question you answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582233/how-to-prove-int-c-dfrac-partial-g-partial-n-ds-iint-r-nabla-2g-dx-dy/1582278#1582278 but is has a similar lack of motivation.  It is possible the *different* people saw questions and downvoted the questions and/or answers for this reason.

Comment: I recently visited [your reputation page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/267844/h-r?tab=reputation). It shows there are only $4$ downvotes, and the $-15$ was for un-acceptance. you need not worry much. If some user continually upvote or downvote you, you [votes will be corrected](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) within $24$ hours, and if you don't see the correction, you may [contact the developers](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, stop being angry. :-) To annoy you might be the point of it all. You see how you make "the attacker" win by getting angry.

Second, wait for a day. There is an automatic script that undoes certain forms of targeted voting.

Third, if it is not undone and the voting is severe, report the issue to the moderators via an "other" flag. It is not clear they can do anything about it, but at least it is on record then.

Comment: Thanks, for the Guides! :) I am calm now! :D

Comment: Glad to know it helped! :-)

Comment: @H.R. Don't be surprised if one or two remain though. Somewhat recently I had a handful of downvotes within seconds, and all but one or two were reversed by a user being deleted.

Comment: @pjs36: That's interesting! Every new post I make is accompanied with a down vote since today! Also, some old posts has been down voted in a minute! I don't know why they do this! :)

Comment: @H.R.: Many of us who have been on the site long enough have experienced this at one point or another.  I even got some beaut who tried to figure out how the algorithm processed downvotes for reversal and then populated me with downvotes so that the site would not notice.  Some dialog with the SE people took care of the problem permanently.  So while I understand it is frustrating and upsetting, it is not an insoluble problem.

Comment: @quid The mods can't do much about this. Only the admins can help him via "contact us".

Comment: @user26857 while this is in some sense true, I intentionally gave the advice to contact the per-site moderators. They can then decide if it is severe enough to escalate. (AFAIK the admins will usually not bother with a handful of votes.)